# How can I hide the variable rendering on JSX React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, rendering, e-commerce

I'm making a e-commerce cart and I displaying the total price value of all items. But when I do a conditional render like this (in case no products is loaded):

```
{cartItems.length &&
            <div>
                <p>Total price: $ {totalPrice} </p>
                <button onClick={confirmPurchase}>Confirm purchase</button>
            </div>}
```

instead of displaying anything, React render a "0" because of the variable "totalPrice". How can I hide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `&&` operator and the first value is falsey (in your case, your `cartItems.length` will evaluate to `0`), it will return the falsey value - `0`.

Another way to achieve this is by using a ternary operator. You could be explicit here and define when you want to show the items and when not:

```
{cartItems.length > 0 ? (
  <div>
    <p>Total price: $ {totalPrice} </p>
    <button onClick={confirmPurchase}>Confirm purchase</button>
  </div>
) : null}
```

Comment: Aaaah, I didn't know about that return. Thank you!